# Binary classification - Class 1 testing metrics are all zeros

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am working on a binary classification problem for Spam/Not spam emails using Keras and tensorflow. Training accuracy is perfect and the AUC as well.
This is the Frequency of the data

```
{"Not Spam(0)": 2500, "Spam(1)": 499}
```

This is the model architecture:

```
LSTM_model=Sequential()
LSTM_model.add(Embedding(2000,8, input_length=100))
LSTM_model.add(LSTM(units=128))
LSTM_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
LSTM_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
LSTM_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
```

Here is the last epoch training

```
Epoch 10/10
33/33 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0227 - acc: 0.9971 - val_loss: 0.0457 - val_acc: 0.9900
training time was: 6.537448167800903
```

And this is the classification report of the Testing data

```
 precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.84      1.00      0.91       754
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       146

    accuracy                           0.84       900
   macro avg       0.42      0.50      0.46       900
weighted avg       0.70      0.84      0.76       900
```

The accuracy is acceptable but the metrics of the data for the second class are all zeros, after some research, I found that the reason might be because of an imbalanced dataset. However, I deleted some rows to balance the dataset and the metrics was as shown below:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.47      1.00      0.64       142
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       158

    accuracy                           0.47       300
   macro avg       0.24      0.50      0.32       300
weighted avg       0.22      0.47      0.30       300
```

and as you can see I still have the same error.
Although the AUC is : 0.9989511111111111
After saving the model in both cases and predicting real-world examples, all examples are predicted false, even when we try some data from the training set.

the prediction was made using this code line

```
 result=model.predict(x_test)
```

and here is the confusion matrices code

```
print(classification_report(y_test,np.argmax(result,axis=1),zero_division=0))
```

Please help.

Comment: You did not include code of how predictions are made and confusion matrices computed.

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: Argmax is used for multi class clasification, so this is not right, you need to threshold predictiona > 0.5